# Power Query Data Merge Issue: Client Project

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I’m facing a challenge with a data model in Power Query. Here’s a breakdown of the tables I’m working with:

1. Purchase Orders (Primary Key: PurchaseOrderID)
2. Purchase Order Lines (Foreign Key: PurchaseOrderID)
3. Sales Orders (Primary Key: SalesOrderID)
4. Sales Order Lines (Foreign Key: SalesOrderID)
5. PurchaseOrderSalesOrder (This table illustrates the relationship between Sales Orders and Purchase Orders. It’s worth noting that some Sales Orders are linked to multiple Purchase Orders.)

My objective is to amalgamate these tables to create a comprehensive master table for subsequent calculations. While I’ve merged these tables in pursuit of a solution, I’ve encountered a specific issue that I need assistance with.

For context, consider a Sales Order associated with two Purchase Orders. When I attempt to merge the Sales Order table to retrieve the corresponding Purchase Orders, the merge process results in the Sales Order being duplicated. This behavior is consistent with a Left Outer Join, yet it also inadvertently doubles the Sales Order Amount due to the duplication.

I’d be willing to compensate anyone who can offer their expertise on a consultancy basis. Appreciate your help!
[Raw tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/if38n.jpg)

Comment: "I’m unable to share the raw data here" --- then make up sample data. How would we know? then provide a sample desired output and commentary on how you get from one to another, and we can start to help

Comment: I personally struggle with answering these. Even though the solution surely screams at anyone with enough experience in Power BI - it is simply not a concise problem that needs addressing, but a full piece of actual work I get paid to do at work. I recommend checking out Upwork or similar sites where you can get in touch with developers looking to make a quick buck.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a Merge issue here, this is how it works.

You will need to re-think your model design. For example you could decide to continue with the merge but have it as only as a bridge table, ie just Sale and Purchase IDs so that there isn't an "facts" in this table.

If you did want the one Fact table, then you could consider having something like:

| SaleOrderId | PurchaseOrderId | Sale Order Amount | Purchase Order Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| S001 |  | $100 |  |
| S001 | P001 |  | $50 |
| S001 | P002 |  | $50 |

Where you have a row just for the Sale Order & Amount.

So, have a think about the design of your model.

##### Additional answer based on the Raw Tables image.

Here is a quick suggestion for you to proceed. In PowerQuery, Merge your SOPO table into the "Purchase Order Line Table" so that the "Purchase Order Line Table" looks like:

| SO | PO | PO LineItem | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SO1 | PO1 | POL1 | 10 |
| SO1 | PO1 | POL2 | 15 |
| SO2 | PO2 | POL1 | 25 |
| SO2 | PO3 | POL1 | 30 |
|  | PO4 | POL1 | 75 |

Then update your data model relationships to:

```
'Sales Order Table'[SO] 1.* 'Sales Order Lines Table'[SO]
'Sales Order Table'[SO] 1.* 'Purchase Order Lines Table'[SO]
'Purchase Order Table'[PO] 1.* 'Purchase Order Lines Table'[PO]
```

Finally, create a few measures:

```
$ SalesOrder = SUM('Sales Order Lines Table'[Value]

$ PurchaseOrder = SUM('Purchase Order Lines Table'[Value]

$ Margin = [$ SalesOrder] - [$ PurchaseOrder]
```

Comment: Hi Sam, I have now added an image with demo tables, your proposed solution makes sense to but I am unable to fully implement it on these tables, could you help more please by looking at those table? Thanks

Comment: Added a second part to the answer above following the Raw tables you shared.